# Can't removeEventlistener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I cant remove Event of rute_button, rute_button.removeEventlistener is not work.
is there something wrong about function tampil_rute(t) ? thanks..

```
function tampil(t)
{
    rute_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tampil_rute(t));
    //tampil_rute(t);
    var _loadertampil:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var _datatampil:XML = new XML();
    _loadertampil.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, readXMLtampil);
    _loadertampil.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost/mall_baru/tampil2.php?id="+t));
    function readXMLtampil(evttampil:Event)
    {
    _datatampil = new XML(evttampil.target.data);
    var tampilanx = _datatampil..tenant_name;
    tampilan.text = String(tampilanx);
    trace("tampilan ="+tampilanx);
    }
}
function tampil_rute(t)
{
    return function( f:MouseEvent ) 
    {
    var c = t.split("_", 2);
    var d:String = String(c[0]);
    var e:Number = Number(c[1]);
    for(var i:Number=1; i<=e; i++)
    {
        tambahan_tampil_rute(d,i);
    }
        rute_button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tampil_rute(t));
    }
}
function tambahan_tampil_rute(d, i)
{
    this["rute_"+d+"_"+i].visible=true;
}
```

Comment: Where's rute_button being defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the returned function by `tampil_rute(t)`, each time you call this function this is returning a new object of type Function, if you want to remove the event listener, you must be sure to pass the same object (Function) to the `removeEventListener` function.

You can fix it as follow:

```
function tampil_rute(t)
{
    var listener:*; // create a variable to store your listener reference

    listener = function( f:MouseEvent ) 
    {
        var c = t.split("_", 2);
        var d:String = String(c[0]);
        var e:Number = Number(c[1]);
        for(var i:Number=1; i<=e; i++)
        {
            tambahan_tampil_rute(d,i);
        }

        rute_button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, listener); // Put the reference here
    }

    return listener; // Return the listener here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fenixkim is right, the event handler returned by the anonymous function is not accessible because there is no reference to it.

An alternative solution though is to store t in a variable.
That way, we eliminate the need for an anonymous function and simplify the removal of the event handler.

```
var t;

function tampil(t)
{
    this.t = t;
    rute_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tampil_rute);
    // rest of code
}

function tampil_rute(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var c = t.split("_", 2);
    var d:String = String(c[0]);
    var e:Number = Number(c[1]);
    for(var i:Number=1; i<=e; i++)
    {
        tambahan_tampil_rute(d,i);
    }
    rute_button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tampil_rute);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass in the parameter for add/remove eventListener.

```
rute_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tampil_rute);
rute_button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tampil_rute);
```